# Virtual environment can't find module that is installed outside the virtual environment

Tags: python, gtk, virtualenv, pythonpath

I am trying to set up a virtual environment on my machine, and I am really having trouble.

EDIT: I set up my virtual environment by installing virtualenvironment1.9 and running:

```
python virtualenv.py -p myVE
```

Then I add the line

```
alias goVE='source ~/virtualenv-1.9/myVE/bin/activate'
```

to my bashrc, and I use goVE to activate the virtual environment.  I get a (myVE) at the beginning of the commandline in terminal, so I think it's working.  It's just losing the gtk module somehow.

END EDIT

Basically, if I try to

```
import gtk
```

in python, it tells me there is no module named gtk.  But outside my virtual environment, gtk imports with no problem.  I decided it was a problem with the path, so I added

```
export VIRTUALENV_EXTRA_SEARCH_DIR=$PYTHONPATH
export VIRTUALENV_EXTRA_SEARCH_DIR=/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0
```

to my bashrc. Since evidently the gtk module was found in the pythonpath, I thought the first line would do it. When that was insufficient, I tried adding a path specifically to the directory where gtk was located, which I verified by trying

```
import gtk
gtk.__file__
```

Since this still didn't work, I tried modifying the virtualenvironment/bin/activate file, so:

```
PATH = ="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH:/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/"
```

Again, this should be included in the original PATH (unless I'm mistaken), but I'm getting desperate so I tried adding it explicitly to the PATH.  For completeness, my PYTHONPATH is set by:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/data/monroe/ebexcode/trunk/GetData/:/home/user1/geach/:/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained how you created your virtual environment so there's no way to tell if that succeeded.  If your virtual environment was created successfully, there's no need to manually munge the paths.

Assuming you have a virtual environment, you haven't demonstrated that you were able to `activate` it.  In order to activate it, you have to run a script in the virtual environment's `bin` directory.  Example, if your virtual environment is in `~/myvenv` and you run bash, activate your virtual environment by issuing this at your prompt:

```
source ~/myvenv/bin/activate
```

At this point you can use this instance of your shell to install packages into your virtual environment:

```
pip install PyGTK
```

Depending on your system installation, this might fail if you do not have all the tools and libraries installed to build the Python GTK bindings.

Comment: I've edited the question to show I am at least activating the VE properly. But I still don't understand why python can't find gtk any more.

Comment: You do not show that you installed GTK.  Once activated, use pip to install GTK in your virtual environment.  Use `pip freeze` to show which packages are installed in your virtual environment.

Comment: gtk was already installed, it just wasn't transitioning to the virtual environment.  I was running into problems installing it in the virtual environment (pip install gtk doesn't work, gives an error that that command only works on windows machines), but I thought I should be able to make the VE find a module that is already installed. Anyway, I figured it out, I added the path to the gtk directory to my PYTHONPATH, and that took care of the error. I don't understand, but it works.